# Regular expression for adding special character to phone number

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I have added the following regular expression for validating a mobile phone number:

```
(^07[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9][0-9]{7,8}$)
```

I want to allow the user to enter a `#` character too and I'm not sure where to fit it in. They may need to enter `#` character after they have dialed a number, or at the beginning of a number to dial a direct number or an extension.

Comment: So your phone numbers accept `,` as well!

Comment: (^07[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9|#][0-9|#]{7,8}$)?

Comment: I am using c# language

Comment: Both acccept the 11 or 12 numbers, however are still not allowing #

Comment: You can use [1-9] rather than [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]?

Comment: @user3378736 Okay. But do you know that the current regex matches 10 or 11 numbers? (if we ignore the commas that can be matched)

Comment: Yes sorry - not 11 or 12.

Comment: How about (^07[1-9#][0-9#]{7,8}$) ?

Comment: @user3378736 Okay, I was just making sure we're talking about the same thing :) Could you give examples of some valid numbers and some invalid ones? Can the hash be in the middle of the number?

Comment: I am testing that now @Knightsy, thank you.

Comment: Yes @Jerry, thank you - we are looking at the same thing! Basically the user can enter the hash befire the number or at the end, when in a call. Valid numbers - #07713874985 OR 07685746376#...

Comment: In which case I would try (^(#)?07[1-9][0-9]{7,8}(#)?$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your current regex matches 'numbers' of the format `07,12345678` as well. So you need to change `[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]` to `[1-9]` (when you have a `-` between two characters in a character class, it usually means that there's a range)

If you want to accept an optional `#` character, you can use the `?` quantifier which means 0 or 1 times.

```
^#?07[1-9][0-9]{7,8}#?$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP3zZ4)

Except that, as you can see in the demo, it will also match numbers with two hashes; one at the front and one at the end. One option to circumvent this is to use some conditionals (which C# can support).

```
^(#)?07[1-9][0-9]{7,8}(?(1)|#?)$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uS9nO9)

`(?(1)|#?)` basically means that if the first hash was matched, then nothing more should be matched. Otherwise, if no hash was initially matched, then it can match a hash, if there is one at the end of the number.

In C#, it will be a bit like this:

```
Regex.Match(myString, @"^(#)?07[1-9][0-9]{7,8}(?(1)|#?)$");
```

Or you could use a negative lookahead to make sure there's never more than one hash in the number:

```
^(?!.*#.*#.*$)#?07[1-9][0-9]{7,8}#?$
```

Comment: Nice way to handle the # only appearing once.